# Installing Twisted on win10

Tags: python, installation, windows-10, twisted

I've looked at similar questions but cannot get past the dreaded message '...not a supported wheel on this platform'. I am doing the following:

```
py -2.7 -m pip install Twisted-20.3.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

where my Python version displays as follows if I run python from cmd.
[image: python version]

I also have Python37 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I upgraded pip and setuptools as follows:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

then I executed

```
py -3.7 -m pip install Twisted-20.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Then all seemed well.

Answer (score 0):

To install using Python 2.7 you just need to do:

```
pip install twisted==20.3.0
```

It should automatically pick the correct wheel distribution for you.